# Oracle BI 12C (12.2.1.4.0) Configuration Assistant Error (Adding default service instance) on Windows Server 2016

Tags: oracle, installation

I'm installing Oracle BI Pub 12c (12.2.1.4.0) on Windows Server 2016, all steps were successfully passed but on "Add Default Service Instance" it throws below error
Not sure what to do now, can someone please help me out here?

```
   [2020-08-18T18:43:46.057+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Executing Step: Add default service instance
   [2020-08-18T18:43:46.088+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Updating security config
   [2020-08-18T18:43:46.119+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Creating BI Service Instance
   [2020-08-18T18:43:46.119+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] See log file: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\config2020-08-18_04-38-31PM\CreateDefaultBIServiceInstance.out
   [2020-08-18T18:43:46.119+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.exec] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Executing: [cmd, /c, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bitools\bin\create_bi_service_instance.cmd, -d, "Default BI Service Instance", -b, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\bi\modules\oracle.biee.application.sample\sample.bar, -o, weblogic, ssi]
   [2020-08-18T18:43:46.119+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.exec] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Logging script stderr and stdout to C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\config2020-08-18_04-38-31PM\CreateDefaultBIServiceInstance.out
   [2020-08-18T18:44:40.821+08:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Failed single shot step: Add default service instance with: Execution of [cmd, /c, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bitools\bin\create_bi_service_instance.cmd, -d, "Default BI Service Instance", -b, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\bi\modules\oracle.biee.application.sample\sample.bar, -o, weblogic, ssi] failed with exit value 1
   [2020-08-18T18:44:40.821+08:00] [bi] [ERROR] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.actions] [tid: 41] [ecid: 0000NG0j7g1EkJp_wPl3iW1VEtED000004,0] Non-skipped failure during configuration action: Execution of [cmd, /c, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bitools\bin\create_bi_service_instance.cmd, -d, "Default BI Service Instance", -b, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\bi\modules\oracle.biee.application.sample\sample.bar, -o, weblogic, ssi] failed with exit value 1[[
   oracle.bi.exec.ExecutionStatusException: Execution of [cmd, /c, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bitools\bin\create_bi_service_instance.cmd, -d, "Default BI Service Instance", -b, D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\bi\modules\oracle.biee.application.sample\sample.bar, -o, weblogic, ssi] failed with exit value 1
       at oracle.bi.exec.StdinProcess.runProcess(StdinProcess.java:106)
       at oracle.bi.exec.ExecScript.executeScript(ExecScript.java:191)
       at oracle.bi.exec.ExecScript.executeSynchronousScript(ExecScript.java:95)
       at oracle.bi.install.config.steps.application.AddDefaultServiceInstanceStep.createServiceInstance(AddDefaultServiceInstanceStep.java:136)
       at oracle.bi.install.config.steps.application.AddDefaultServiceInstanceStep.executeSingleShot(AddDefaultServiceInstanceStep.java:76)
       at oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps.SingleShotActionStep.execute(SingleShotActionStep.java:31)
       at oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps.StepList.execute(StepList.java:85)
       at oracle.bi.install.config.actions.BIConfigAction.doExecute(BIConfigAction.java:127)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:405)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:88)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:108)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.performSequentialExecution(RequestQueue.java:284)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:260)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:185)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:82)
       at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:87)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   ]]
```

And under **CreateDefaultBIServiceInstance.out** logs, it is showing below error

```
    Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

    Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

    Type help() for help on available commands

    Aug 18, 2020 6:44:40 PM oracle.security.audit.Auditor init
    WARNING: IAU:IAU-6012: Unable to determine the audit log directory. No log directory specified.
    Aug 18, 2020 6:44:40 PM oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.internal.jps.CredentialStoreAccessImpl getPasswordCredential
    WARNING: Password credential not found: Map: oracle.bi.system; Key: datasource.biplatform
    Aug 18, 2020 6:44:40 PM oracle.bi.servicelcm.PodManager getBIPod
    SEVERE: Failed to retrieve pod: oracleHome: d:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\..; domainHome: D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery.getBiPlatformDataSourceWhenStandalone(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:88)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery$1.run(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:54)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery$1.run(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:48)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery.getBiPlatformDataSource(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:48)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.db.DatabaseServiceLcmApi.<init>(DatabaseServiceLcmApi.java:202)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.db.DatabaseServiceLcmApi.<init>(DatabaseServiceLcmApi.java:35)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.db.DatabaseServiceLcmApi$Builder.build(DatabaseServiceLcmApi.java:161)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.DefaultServiceLcmApi$BuilderAdaptor.build(DefaultServiceLcmApi.java:187)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.DefaultServiceLcmApi$Builder.build(DefaultServiceLcmApi.java:95)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm.PodManager.getBIPod(PodManager.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyObject.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx129._getPod$13(/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/lib/bi-servicelcm-api.jar!/wlstScriptDir/biServiceInstanceLCM.py:209)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx129.call_function(/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/lib/bi-servicelcm-api.jar!/wlstScriptDir/biServiceInstanceLCM.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx129.createBIServiceInstance$5(/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/lib/bi-servicelcm-api.jar!/wlstScriptDir/biServiceInstanceLCM.py:85)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx129.call_function(/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/lib/bi-servicelcm-api.jar!/wlstScriptDir/biServiceInstanceLCM.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx145.f$0(D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\syscomp\createBIServiceInstance.py:57)
        at org.python.pycode._pyx145.call_function(D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\syscomp\createBIServiceInstance.py)
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1226)
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.management.scripting.WLST.main(WLST.java:186)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at weblogic.WLST.main(WLST.java:47)


    Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
      File "D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\modules\oracle.bi.sysman\syscomp\createBIServiceInstance.py", line 57, in ?
      File "/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/lib/bi-servicelcm-api.jar!/wlstScriptDir/biServiceInstanceLCM.py", line 85, in createBIServiceInstance
      File "/D:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/bi/lib/bi-servicelcm-api.jar!/wlstScriptDir/biServiceInstanceLCM.py", line 209, in _getPod
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery.getBiPlatformDataSourceWhenStandalone(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:88)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery$1.run(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:54)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery$1.run(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:48)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.configuration.BiPlatformDiscovery.getBiPlatformDataSource(BiPlatformDiscovery.java:48)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.db.DatabaseServiceLcmApi.<init>(DatabaseServiceLcmApi.java:202)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.db.DatabaseServiceLcmApi.<init>(DatabaseServiceLcmApi.java:35)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.db.DatabaseServiceLcmApi$Builder.build(DatabaseServiceLcmApi.java:161)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.DefaultServiceLcmApi$BuilderAdaptor.build(DefaultServiceLcmApi.java:187)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm_v2.DefaultServiceLcmApi$Builder.build(DefaultServiceLcmApi.java:95)
        at oracle.bi.servicelcm.PodManager.getBIPod(PodManager.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```